# How best to attach multiple network interfaces to aws_instance in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to add a list of interfaces to an aws_instance as follows:

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.this
  instance_type = "c5.4xlarge"

  user_data = var.user_data

  network_interface {
    count                = length(var.network_interfaces)
    network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.this[count.index].id
    device_index         = count.index + 0

  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.prefix}-hub-1"
  }
}
```

But this is the error I get:

```
 Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context

   on ..\cloudhub_aws\aws_c8000v\main.tf line 146, in resource "aws_instance" "this":
  146:     network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.this[count.index].id

 The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you mind adding the second resource to the question, i.e., `aws_network_interface`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define network interface attachment in aws_network_interface resource

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "this" {
  count = length(var.network_interfaces)

  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.public_a.id
  private_ips     = ["10.0.0.50"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.web.id]

  attachment {
    instance     = aws_instance.this.id
    device_index = count.index
  }
}
```